# Is there a connection between primitive elements (for field extensions) and cyclic vectors (in linear algebra)

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field

I'm allergic to finite fields, so let's work in characteristic $0$. The primitive element theorem states:

> **Primitive element theorem:** Let $E / F$ be a finite-dimensional field extension,  say $n =[E:F]$. Then, there exists an element $\alpha \in E$ such that $E = F[\alpha]$.

The following is not really a "theorem" so much as a basic fact from linear algebra, but anyway:

> **Cyclic vector theorem:** Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$, say $\mathrm{dim}(V)=n$. Let $T : V \to V$ be a linear transformation with minimum polynomial $m$. If $\mathrm{deg}(m) = \mathrm{dim}(V)$, then there is a vector $v \in V$ such that $v,Tv,\ldots,T^{n-1}v$ is a basis for $V$.

When your extension $E/F$ is singly-generated over $F$ by $\alpha$, you can consider the minimum polynomial (now in the sense of an algebraic element over a field) $m$ of the element $\alpha$, which is irreducible and has degree $n = [E:F]$. It is sort of obvious in this situation that $T : E \to E$ given by $T(\beta) = \alpha \beta$ is an $F$-linear transformation whose minimum polynomial (in the sense of linear algebra) is also $m$. Any nonzero element is a cyclic vector for this transformation. Perhaps $1 \in E$ is a particularly natural choice. So, anyway, there is at least some sort of superficial connection between the boxed results above. But I really want to know if there is a *useful* connection. I would especially like to know:

> **Question:** Is there some way to cleverly set things up so that the primitive element theorem becomes a *consequence* of the "cyclic vector theorem"? If not, can the notion of a cyclic vector at least be used to *clarify* the primitive element theorem somehow?

Comment: I strongly think the answer is no. Of course since the question is not formally stated I can't prove it,  but in in order to state something definite let me bet that nobody will post a positive answer before, say, November 30, 23:59:59 GMT :-)

Comment: I don't want to spell out all my reasons for my bet, but one of them is that one has to distinguish between finite base field and infinite base field for a theorem whose statement cares only about separable extensions. Separability of the base field plays no role in the cyclic vector theorem, so that a proof of primitivity using pure linear algebra shouldn't have to distinguish cases.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another attempt at an "answer". I'm going to try and argue that the "cyclic vector theorem" perhaps does deserve to be called a theorem, and one way of proving it (or at least a crucial step in proving it) also proves a version of the primitive element theorem. The following Definition is completely standard, but I spell out the details partly to set up some notation, and partly to emphasize that I'm trying to keep the arguments as elementary as possible.

**Definition**: Let $\alpha\colon V\to V$ and suppose that $v \in V$. The $\alpha$-stable subspace $C_{\alpha}(v)$ generated by $v$ is defined to be $\bigcap_{v \in W} W$ where the intersection is taken over all $\alpha$-stable subspaces $W$ containing $v$.

We can describe $C_{\alpha}(v)$ more concretely as follows: let $k$ be the largest positive integer such that $\{v,\alpha(v),\alpha^2(v), \ldots, \alpha^{k-1}(v)\}$ is a linearly independent set. Then $\alpha^k(v)$ lies in $ \text{span}\{v,\alpha(v),\ldots,\alpha^{k-1}(v)\}$, hence there are scalars $\lambda_i$ $(0\leq i\leq k-1)$ with
$$
\alpha^k(v)+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\lambda_i\alpha^i(v) = 0
$$
Let $p_v(t) = t^k+\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\lambda_it^i$ so that $p_v(\alpha)(v)=0$, and $p_v$ is the monic polynomial of smallest degree with this property. But then $p_v(\alpha)\alpha^j(v) = \alpha^jp_v(\alpha)(v)=0$, hence $p_v(\alpha)$ acts by zero on a basis of $C_{\alpha}(v)$, and thus $p_v(\alpha_{|C_{\alpha}(v)})=0$. But clearly any polyomial of degree less than $k$ cannot annihilate $v$, and so $p_v$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_{|C_{\alpha}(v)}$.
Note that $(V,\alpha)$ is *cyclic* (or *has a cyclic vector*) if $V = C_{\alpha}(v)$ for some $v \in V$, where $v$ is the cyclic vector.

**Lemma**:
Suppose that $\alpha\colon V\to V$ has a cyclic vector $v_0 \in V$. Then if $m_\alpha(t) \in F[t]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, then the map which assigns to an $\alpha$-stable subspace $W$ of $V$ the characteristic polynomial $m_W$ of the restriction $\alpha_{|W}$ of $\alpha$ to $W$ gives a bijective correspondence between the $\alpha$-stable subspaces and the the divisors of $m_{\alpha}$, with the inverse map being given by associating to $d \mid m_{\alpha}$, the subspace
$$
V_d := \frac{m_{\alpha}}{d}(\alpha)(V)= C_{\alpha}((m_{\alpha}/d)(\alpha)(v_0)).
$$
**Proof**:
First note that since $v_0$ is a cyclic vector, given any vector $v \in V$ there is a unique polynomial $g(t)\in F[t]$ with $\deg(g)<d=\dim(V)=\deg(m_\alpha)$ and $v=g(\alpha)(v_0)$.
Now suppose that $W$ is an $\alpha$-stable subspace of $V$, and let $m_W$ be the minimal polynomial of $\alpha_{|W}$. Since the minimal polynomial of a linear map divides any polynomial that the linear map satisfies, we have $m_W\mid m$, hence if $w \in W$ and we write $w = g(\alpha)(v_0)$ it follows that $m_W(\alpha)g(\alpha)(v_0)=0$. But then we must have $m_{\alpha}\mid m_W.g$, and hence $(m_{\alpha}/m_W) \mid g$. It follows that if we let $d = m_{\alpha}/m_W$, then $W = C_{\alpha}(d(\alpha)(v_0))$ as required. The equality $C_{\alpha}(d(\alpha)(v_0)) = d(\alpha)(V)$ is immediate from the definitions.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

Here is where I want to try and make a case for the cylic vector theorem, though I'm going to cheat a bit and state a slightly stronger theorem:

**Theorem**:
Let $V$ be a non-zero vector space and let $\alpha\colon V\to V$ be a linear map. The minimal polynomial $m\in F[t]$ of $\alpha$ has $\deg(m)\leq \dim(V)$ with equality if and only if $V$ is cyclic, that is, $V= C_{\alpha}(v)$ for some $v \in V$.

**Remark**:
Before proving this, it is perhaps worth noting that the elementary argument that $m_{\alpha}$ exists uses the fact that $\{\alpha^k: k\in\mathbb Z_{\geq 0}\}$ is an infinite set in a finite dimensional vector space, namely $\text{End}(V)$, so $\dim(\text{End}(V))+1$ elements in it must be linearly dependent. This gives one the bound $\text{deg}(m_{\alpha}) \leq \dim(V)^2$, which is much cruder than the precise bound given by the theorem. The fact that $\deg(m_{\alpha})\leq \dim(V)$ is usually proved by establishing the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

**Proof**:
We prove the theorem by induction on $\deg(m)$. If $\deg(m)=1$ then $m(\alpha)=\alpha-\lambda$ for some $\lambda \in F$, and as $V\neq \{0\}$ we have $1\leq \dim(V)$, where if $\dim(V)=1$ then any $v \in V$ is a cyclic vector, while if $\dim(V)>1$ clearly $(V,\alpha)$ cannot be cyclic. Thus we may suppose that $\alpha\colon V\to V$ is a linear map with $d=\deg(m_\alpha)>1$ and that the statement of the theorem is known for endomorphisms of a vector space with minimal polynomial of degree less than $d$. Suppose for the sake of a contradiction, that the theorem is false for linear maps $\alpha$ with $\deg(m_{\alpha}) = d$. Then we may assume we have a counter-example with $\dim(V)$ minimal, and hence if $\beta\colon W\to W$ is a linear map with $\deg(m_{\beta})\leq d$ and $\dim(W)<\dim(V)$, then we may assume the theorem holds for $\beta$.

Let us say that $v\in V$ is *regular* if $k=\dim(C_{\alpha}(v))$ is maximal. By assumption $k<d=dim(V)$. Fix $v_0\in V$ a regular vector, let $W = C_{\alpha}(v_0)$, and consider $Q = V/W$. Since any linear map $\beta\colon V\to V$ with $\beta(W)\subseteq W$ induces a linear map $\overline{\beta}\colon Q\to Q$, for any $q(t)\in F[t]$, $q(\alpha)$ induces a linear map $\overline{q(\alpha)}=q(\overline{\alpha})\in \text{End}(Q)$. Now $m(\overline{\alpha}) = \overline{m(\alpha)} = \overline{0}$, hence if we write $m_Q(t)$ for the minimal polynomial of $\overline{\alpha}$, we have $m_Q\mid m$. In particular, $\deg(m_Q)\leq \deg(m)$ and $\dim(Q)\leq \dim(V)-1$. Hence by induction and the minimality of $\dim(V)$ we may conclude that $\deg(m_Q)\leq \dim(Q) = \dim(V)-k$.

But now consider $(p_v.m_Q)(\alpha)$. If $u \in V$ then $m_Q(\bar{\alpha})(u+W_0) = 0+W_0$ by definition of $m_Q$ and hence $m_Q(\alpha)(u)\in W_0$. But then $p_v(\alpha)(m_Q(\alpha)(u)=0$ so that $(p_v.m_Q)(\alpha) =0$ and hence $m\mid p_v.m_Q$. Since
$$
\deg(p_v.m_Q) = k+\deg(m_Q)\leq k+\dim(Q) = \dim(V),
$$
it follows that $\deg(m)\leq \dim(V)$, with equality only if $\deg(m_Q)=\dim(Q)$, which, by induction we know implies $Q$ is cyclic. Thus for $(V,\alpha)$ to be a counter-example, we must have $\deg(m_{\alpha})=\dim(V)$, $(Q,\bar{\alpha})$ cyclic, but $(V,\alpha)$ fail to be cyclic.

Now $(W,\alpha)$ and $(Q,\bar{\alpha})$ are cyclic, hence, as in Lemma above, the $\alpha$-stable subspaces of $W$ are the spaces $W_c$ for $c\mid p$. Similarly the $\bar{\alpha}$-stable subspaces of $Q$ are the $Q_d$ for $d\mid m_Q$, and we set $U_d = \pi^{-1}(Q_d)$ where $\pi\colon V \to V/W$ is the quotient map, so that the $U_d$ are precisely the $\alpha$-stable subspaces of $V$ which contain $W$. Now if, for any $d\mid m_Q$, $d\neq m_Q$ we have $m_Q(\alpha)(U_d) = m_Q(\alpha)(V)\subseteq W$, then $(p.d)(\alpha)=0$ so that $m_{\alpha}\mid p.d$ and hence $\deg(m_\alpha)<\dim(V)$. Similarly if $m_Q(\alpha)(\alpha)(V) = W_d$ for $d$ a proper divisor of $p$, then $(d.m_Q)(\alpha)=0$ and again $m_{\alpha}\mid d.m_Q$ and hence $\deg(m_{\alpha})<\dim(V)$. Thus $m_Q(\alpha)(V) = W$ and $m_Q(\alpha)(U_d)\lneq W$ for all proper divisors $d$ of $m_Q$. But any vector $u \in V\backslash \bigcup_{d\mid m_Q, d\neq m_Q} U_d$ has $u+W$ a cyclic vector for $\bar{\alpha}$ and $m_Q(\alpha)(u) \in W\backslash \bigcup_{c\mid p, c\neq p} W_c$, so that $m_Q(\alpha)(u)$ is a cyclic vector for $\alpha_{|W}$. It follows immediately that $u$ is a cyclic vector for $V$, and hence $(V,\alpha)$ is not a counterexample, contradicting our assumption.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$

**What about the primitive element theorem**: A weak form of the conclusion of the Lemma is in fact equivalent to the existence of cyclic vectors for $\alpha$ provided $F$ is infinite: Namely the Lemma shows that if $\alpha\colon V\to V$ has a cyclic vector then there are only finitely many $\alpha$-stable subspaces of $V$. But over an infinite field, a vector space cannot be a finite union of proper subspaces, hence there must be a vector which does not lie in any proper $\alpha$-stable subspace of $V$. It follows immediately that such a vector must be a cyclic vector for $\alpha$. Exactly the same strategy (considering the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ shows that a simple extension $E=F(\alpha)$ has only finitely many subfields, and if $E/F$ is a finite extension of fields has only finitely many subfields, provided the field is infinite, any element $f \in E$ which does not lie in any of the finitely many subfields must be a primitive element. This, combined with the Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, immediately implies the primitive element theorem.

Comment: +1, thanks for contributing all those details!

Answer (score 0):

We need a minimal polynomial with degree equal to the dimension of $V$ to apply cyclic vector theorem. So if you take $E=V$ you need a polynomal of degree $[E:F]$ and the only good choice for this polynomial I see is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$.

What you can do is to view the cyclic vector theorem as special case of the primitive element theorem. Use the cyclic vector theorem or the [structure theorem for finitely generated modules over a principal ideal domain](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_theorem_for_finitely_generated_modules_over_a_principal_ideal_domain) to identity $V$ with $L=F[X]/(m)$  such that $T$ is represented by the multiplication by $X$. Now if you forget the morphism $T$ you can recover it from $L/F$ using the primitive element theorem and you get the  cyclic vector basically for free.

Not sure if it is helpful what I wrote. It looks a bit made up for me. Maybe it is helps anyway.